# Using Mapbox JSON data to highlight features

Tags: popup, mapbox, highlight, mapbox-gl-js

Good afternoon,

I am using the following example (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/query-similar-features/).

I read the forum carefully but did not find something quite related.
My data is displaying correctly. However the popup function is still not working at all.

Here my latest fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/wbmv24a0/3/).

```html
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Highlight features containing similar data</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<style>
.map-overlay {
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}
</style>

<div id='map'></div>
<div id='map-overlay' class='map-overlay'></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGhlbWF0aXgiLCJhIjoiY2pnZG9iY2U3MzJxYjMybGhmMDUxZ3Z1NCJ9.WLqfBodKltXx-wx6_3Tw4w';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-70, 53],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 4
});

var overlay = document.getElementById('map-overlay');

// Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeButton: false
});

map.on('load', function() {
    // Add the source to query. In this example we're using
    // ecoregion polygons uploaded as vector tiles
    map.addSource('reg_eco', {
        "type": "vector",
        "url": "mapbox://thematix.6pzptrfa"
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "regeco",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "reg_eco",
        "source-layer": "reg_eco-5jav3d",
        "paint": {
            "fill-outline-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
            "fill-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
        }
    }, 'place-city-sm'); // Place polygon under these labels.

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "regecoh",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "reg_eco",
        "source-layer": "reg_eco-5jav3d",
        "paint": {
            "fill-outline-color": "#484896",
            "fill-color": "#6e599f",
            "fill-opacity": 0.75
        },
        "filter": ["in", "REG_ECO", ""]
    }, 'place-city-sm'); // Place polygon under these labels.

    map.on('mousemove', 'reg_eco', function(e) {
        // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

        // Single out the first found feature.
        var feature = e.features[0];

        // Query the ecoregion layer visible in the map. Use the filter
        // param to only collect results that share the same ecoregion name.
        var relatedFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures('reg_eco', {
            sourceLayer: 'reg_eco-5jav3d',
            filter: ['in', 'REG_ECO', feature.properties.REG_ECO]
        });

        // Render found features in an overlay.
        overlay.innerHTML = '';

        // Add features that share the same ecoregion name to the highlighted layer.
        map.setFilter('regecoh', ['in', 'REG_ECO', feature.properties.REG_ECO]);

        // Display a popup with the name of the ecoregion
        popup.setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setText(feature.properties.REG_ECO)
            .addTo(map);
    });

    map.on('mouseleave', 'reg_eco', function() {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
        popup.remove();
        map.setFilter('regecoh', ['in', 'REG_ECO', '']);
        overlay.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>`
```

I cannot figure out why it is not working.

Thanking everybody in advance.

Pierre-Y. Plourde

Comment: You need to provide more information than "it is still not working at all". What is not working? What have you tried to fix it? Try reducing your code down to the absolute minimum, rather than pasting everything here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will be careful next time with the code. As you can see by the mapbox example link provided at the beginning of the post, when you hover a polygon with the pointer, data with similar attributes should be highlighted. I cannot reproduce this behavior. Besides inserting my own data, the only modification to the original code was to remove this code portion ( // Total the population of all features) which is not needed for my purpose.

Comment: There's still a lot of code there. I can't see the polygons that are meant to be loading, but I also don't know where they're meant to be.

Comment: I will probably modify the dataset in order to get a full view of these polygons at zoom level 0. Several of these features share a common name. I was hoping with this example to highlight them all at once with a single click.